# how to handle touch events in android with opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

How to handle touchscreen events for OpenGl programs in Android? I have checked out several posts related to this question, like-
[How to intercept touchscreen events in Android OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453855/how-to-intercept-touchscreen-events-in-android-opengl-es)
But my problem is that I am only able to handle MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN events, even if I write the handler for other type of events, those handlers are not called.Android docs sample also uses this event only.Are the other events supported??
My `onTouch` handler looks something like this-

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
      Log.d(TAG, "mode=DOWN");
      break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP :
      Log.d(TAG, "mode=UP");
          break;
      }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a series of if/else statements and see if they work, then try converting it to a switch statement. Maybe take out break and instead return true.

This is how I do it:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final float mouseSensitivity = 0.5f;

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
            } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                startX = 0.0f;
                startY = 0.0f;
            } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                graphicsRenderer.rotate((startY - event.getY()) * mouseSensitivity,(startX - event.getX()) * mouseSensitivity);
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
            }

            return true;
        }

// Where startX and startY are global int variables;
```